# No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxBind' in package 'AndroidApp.Droid'

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

The solution was running fine before till I have added Menu to the application and build, it gave me above error. My code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/AndroidApp.Droid"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Mvx.MvxListView
       local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MenuItems; ItemClick SelectMenuItemCommand"
       local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_menu"
       android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="#111" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Any Solution For this?
I have tried 
       1) xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/AndroidApp.Droid" and
       2) xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
but it isn't working now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the file _MvxBindingAttributes.xml_ in the _Resources/Values_ folder? It should be there by default, but may have accidentally been deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hows, some reference are not getting properly, please clean and build your project and the if still getting problems then check your package name also. I hope that is useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Package name from Manifest have to be the same with

```
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Sample.Android"
```

[image]